# How to record multitouch gestures in Kivy?

Tags: gesture, kivy

I have used the [gestures code based on the provided Kivy examples](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/gestures/gesture_board.py) to record and recognize single touch gestures. However, I am not sure how to extend this code to recognize multi-touch gestures. Let's say, for example, a pinch.

My problem becomes specially complicated because I use a laptop with zero multi-touch functionality. How do I combine two single gestures? Is there any example available?

Comment: I understand the edit, but not the reason why it was [down voted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). Can you explain me why? If tito, the creator of kivy bothered answering the question, it might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 1.9.0, Kivy got a multi-touch gesture recognizer integrated: have a look at  [kivy.multistroke](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/multistroke.py). I personally didn't got time to test it yet.

If you want to map or act depending of the gesture, you might be interested by the [Scatter](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scatter.html). Pinch can be done with 2 to N touch, with rotation and translation integrated. You can restrict the transformation to just scale and not rotation / translation. And, when all the touches are released, you could animate the scale to the closest wanted value. You can also set a limit for the minimum scale and maximum scale.

With few parameters and code, you can pinch to zoom, de/un pinch to unzoom, etc. Maybe that's what you want :) (like pinch to zoom in a image, or put an image in fullscreen).

You can also just use the Scatter's scale parameters, or Scale's matrix to do your own things :)