# How to make a scrollview with pinch-zoom for the text-size in kivy?

Tags: kivy, pinchzoom, scrollable, text-size

I am looking for the code in kivy to build a pinch-zoom scrollview of a long text that changes the text size based on how it is pinched. It seems like a pretty common feature in android book-reading apps.

I looked all over but it seems no one else has tried this yet. It looks like one would need to do something along [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210370/how-to-record-multitouch-gestures-in-kivy) .  Any help would be appreciated.